# PHPunit show only class and line in failed tests

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a lot of tests and the output is unreadable if some of them are failed at once. I need to scroll a lot of stack traces to understand where another failed test starts. 
It would be really great if I can output like this, without text of errors:

```
There were 4 failures:

1) TestClassName1:testMethodName1 line 14
2) TestClassName2:testMethodName2 line 23
3) TestClassName1:testMethodName3 line 56
4) TestClassName1:testMethodName4 line 34
```

I believe there is some option, but i cannot find anything.

Comment: There's no stack traces when a test fails so I don't know what you mean there.

Comment: @sg-
There are. Not in every case, but happens. Proof: http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/17/1110/h_1510315341_7102204_fe423d43dd.png

Comment: That's not a test failing. That's an Exception thrown by php code which is very different. PHPunit won't neatly summarize your Exceptions because your code is supposed to work. Right now you have bugs. You have to fix the bugs so that there's no unintended exceptions. Then, if an actual test assertion fails it will be neatly summarized for you.

Comment: @sg- The main purpose of tests is to help find bugs. And to find the code that doesn't work. What is the point of PHPunit if I am not supposed to run it until I have all the bugs fixed?

Comment: Running the tests helps you find bugs just like using the software helps you find bugs, but it's not the purpose of either. PHPunit's job is to test assertions. That is all. So it will do a good job of summarizing failed assertions but it's not going to neatly summarize exceptions because it's not designed to find or handle broken code. It's only job is to test assertions.

Comment: @sg- Here is the example of failed assertion: http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/17/1110/h_1510319202_5239977_bc25d354d0.png
No bugs. It still takes a lot of screen space (it is not even a real html page, real page can be 30 times as long).

Comment: That html code is displaying because you are forcing PHPunit to display it when the assertion fails. Have a look at the source code for that assertion and you will find you are echoing out that html code or passing it as a 3rd parameter.

Comment: @sg- Yes, it is echoed out here: https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing/blob/167d459a8b7a1b93b00df675746dccfa1655ef78/src/Constraints/PageConstraint.php#L71
How can I influence it? It is not passed as a 3rd parameter.

Comment: I see. You didn't mention you were using Laravrel BrowserKit. Well, that's slightly more difficult seeing it appears to spew out all of the html by default. However at least this has pointed you in a new direction in that your beef is with Laravel and not PHPunit. Hopefully you are able to find a solution in a Laravel forum or by posting an issue on their GitHub.